# Quickly generate Excel/XLSX by writing Huge Data to File in Spring Boot using MongoDB

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi, xlsx

I want to export huge data to excel file quickly. Currently, I am using Apache POI for exporting excel file but it takes a lot of time in iteration for writing data to each row.
I am trying to write more than 40,000 rows to excel but it takes more than 10 mins to generate the file.

I am using `SXSSFWorkbook` and also using an iterator to remove the list element after writing it to row to minimise the memory issue.

Below is my code

```
public ByteArrayInputStream generateExcel(String fromDate, String toDate, String locationType, String locationId) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"Role", "Name", "Phone Number", "ETC.."};

        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE/* 100 */);
        wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);

        SXSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet("Personal Details");
        sh.setRandomAccessWindowSize(100);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());

        CellStyle headerCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        // Row for Header
        Row headerRow = sh.createRow(0);

        // Header
        for (int col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
            cell.setCellValue(columns[col]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }
        // Fetch Data From MongoDB
        List<User> farmerList = userRepo.getFarmerList(fromDate, toDate, locationId);        
        int rowIdx = 1;

        Iterator<User> i = farmerList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            User farmer = i.next();
            SXSSFRow row = sh.createRow(rowIdx++);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(getUserMainRole(farmer));
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(farmer.getFirstName() + " " + farmer.getLastName());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(farmer.getPrimaryPhone());
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(agentName);
            i.remove();
        }

        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

I want to improve the speed of two things:

1. Fetching Data from MongoDB: I am using indexing
2. Improve speed of iterator

Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this or if there is another way of generating excel file?

Comment: Run a profiler on your code, and identify the slowest bits?

Comment: @Gagravarr the loop is taking time for inserting data to row.

Comment: Which bit of the loop though? And where? We need more profiling info...